# Circle inside Circle

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uipangesturerecognizer

Trying to fix the error:

> Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGFloat' and 'Double'.

I have tried `let centerRadius: CGFloat = 37.5` and `let whiteDotRadius: CGFloat = 23.5.` The code runs, but doesn't print the statement when whiteDot is inside the center. How could I fix the error message?

```
 let centerRadius = 37.5
    let whiteDotRadius = 23.5

    let whiteDotDist = hypot(center.center.x - whiteDot.center.x, center.center.y - whiteDot.center.y - whiteDot.center.y)

    if whiteDotDist < centerRadius - whiteDotRadius {
        print("Inside")
    }
```

[image: screenshot from the circles]

Comment: so what's the problem/

Comment: It says in the question what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

Change your if statement to this

```
if CFGFloat(whiteDotDist) < CFGFloat(centerRadius - whiteDotRadius)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It got rid of the error message, but still isn't printing out. I guess there must be something wrong with my code then?

Comment: My answer gets rid of the error and makes your statement logically correct. However what's center.center.x so I can help you out? (PS: If this answer was helpful please up vote or mark as correct if it solves your problem)